# Generating similar methods via loop in R package

Tags: r, generics, methods, r-s4

I tried to write a for loop to create getters and setters for slots of an S4 class.

A similar reprex with a smaller class and only methods for the getters is:

```r
library(methods)
library(testthat)

get_slot <- function(slot) {
  function(x) slot(x, slot)
}

setClass("TEST", slots = list(a = "character", b = "character"))

for (e in c("a", "b")) {
  def <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("function(x) standardGeneric('%s')", e)))
  setGeneric(e, def = def)
  setMethod(e, "TEST", get_slot(e))
}

test_that("getters work", {
  o <- new("TEST")
  o@a <- "a"
  o@b <- "b"
  expect_equal(a(o), "a")
  expect_equal(b(o), "b")
})
#> ── Failure ('<text>:20:3'): getters work ───────────────────────────────────────
#> a(o) not equal to "a".
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> x[1]: "b"
#> y[1]: "a"
#> Error in `reporter$stop_if_needed()`:
#> ! Test failed
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. └─testthat::test_that(...)
#>   2.   └─withr (local) `<fn>`(`<env>`)
#>   3.     ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>   4.     │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>   5.     │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>   6.     │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   7.     └─base::eval(handler$expr, handler$envir)
#>   8.       └─base::eval(handler$expr, handler$envir)
#>   9.         └─reporter$stop_if_needed()
#>  10.           └─rlang::abort("Test failed") at testthat/R/reporter-stop.R:56:8

getMethod("a", signature = "TEST")
#> Method Definition:
#> 
#> function (x) 
#> slot(x, slot)
#> <environment: 0x55bb459bec98>
#> 
#> Signatures:
#>         x     
#> target  "TEST"
#> defined "TEST"
getMethod("b", signature = "TEST")
#> Method Definition:
#> 
#> function (x) 
#> slot(x, slot)
#> <bytecode: 0x55bb45b97558>
#> <environment: 0x55bb45ab1258>
#> 
#> Signatures:
#>         x     
#> target  "TEST"
#> defined "TEST"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would expect that `a(o)` is equal to `"a"` and `b(o)` is equal to `"b"`. I do not understand why the slot argument is wrong not correct for the first getter.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what's going on, but if you `eval()` and `parse()` the whole `setGeneric()` and `setMethod()` functions, it works.  Generally people don't like eval-parse answers, but it does work here.

```r
library(methods)
library(testthat)

get_slot <- function(slot) {
  function(x) slot(x, slot)
}

setClass("TEST", slots = list(a = "character", b = "character"))

for(e in c("a", "b")){
  eval(parse(text = sprintf("setGeneric('%s', def=function(x) standardGeneric('%s'))", e, e)))
  eval(parse(text = sprintf("setMethod('%s', 'TEST', get_slot('%s'))", e, e)))
}

test_that("getters work", {
  o <- new("TEST")
  o@a <- "a"
  o@b <- "b"
  expect_equal(a(o), "a")
  expect_equal(b(o), "b")
})
#> Test passed
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First, I will change the argument `slot` in function `get_slot` to `s` as `slot` is an existing R function. I think this is a good practice.
**1.** Now we have:

```r
get_slot <- function(s) {
    function(x) slot(x, s)
}
```

**2.** We continue with your code:

```
setClass("TEST", slots = list(a = "character", b = "character"))

for (e in c("a", "b")) {
    def <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("function(x) standardGeneric('%s')", e)))
    setGeneric(e, def = def)
    setMethod(e, "TEST", get_slot(e)) # NOTE: Due to this call, variable e is link to argument s within function get_slot above
}

o <- new("TEST")
o@a <- "a"
o@b <- "b"

### The results are
> e
[1] "b"

> getMethod("a", "TEST")
Method Definition:

function (x) 
slot(x, s)
<environment: 0x000001989e703ef0>

Signatures:
        x     
target  "TEST"
defined "TEST"

> getMethod("b", "TEST")
Method Definition:

function (x) 
slot(x, s)
<bytecode: 0x000001989e3dddd0>
<environment: 0x000001989e628d90>

Signatures:
        x     
target  "TEST"
defined "TEST"

> o
An object of class "TEST"
Slot "a":
[1] "a"

Slot "b":
[1] "b"
```

At this stage, nothing is evaluated due to lazy evaluation. Only when you call `a(o)` does R starts evaluating things. So, the current value of `e = "b"` is used, variable `e` is link to argument `s` within function `get_slot`, and you have:

```r
a(o) # "b"
b(o) # "b"
```

You can play around by clearing all variables, refresh R sessions (Rstudio > Session > Restart R) then run **1** and **2** above, then:

```r
e <- "a"
a(o) # "a"
b(o) # "a"

### Clear all variables and refresh R sessions, then run 1 and 2 above then

e <- "a"
a(o) # "a"
e <- "b"
b(o) # "b"
```

To sum it up, this is the result of lazy evaluation and the way functions work in R. You can read more [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html#forcing-evaluation) and `help(force)` (read through the "Examples" section for ease of understanding). To fix it, simply add `force(s)` to `get_slot` to force evaluation of `s` and capture its value for the next statement `function(x) slot(x, s)`:

```r
get_slot <- function(s) {
    force(s)
    function(x) slot(x, s)
}
```

P.S. Regarding comment about avoiding `eval(parse())` you can improve by using `eval(substitute())` or `eval(bquote())`:

```
for (e in c("a", "b")) {
    eval(substitute(setGeneric(sn, function(x) standardGeneric(sn)), list(sn = e)))
    # eval(bquote(setGeneric(.(e), function(x) standardGeneric(.(e)))))
    setMethod(e, "TEST", get_slot(e))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! This solves the problem I asked for in the question. But in my real package, I the elements I loop through is defined in an internal rda data. While devtools::test() works, the testing part of devtools::check() fails because it does not find the internal data. Do you know why this happens?